# n-cpu failure after running ./stack.sh

Tags: deployment, openstack, openstack-nova, vcenter

---

Error while running `./stack.sh` after inserting my vCentre details in the localrc file for getting the list of VM from my vCentre Server onto Openstack

Log:

```
2016-08-01 07:20:14.416 | +functions-common:service_check:1633       local service
2016-08-01 07:20:14.422 | +functions-common:service_check:1634       local failures
2016-08-01 07:20:14.428 | +functions-common:service_check:1635       SCREEN_NAME=stack
2016-08-01 07:20:14.434 | +functions-common:service_check:1636       SERVICE_DIR=/opt/stack/status
2016-08-01 07:20:14.441 | +functions-common:service_check:1639       [[ ! -d /opt/stack/status/stack ]]
2016-08-01 07:20:14.449 | ++functions-common:service_check:1646       ls /opt/stack/status/stack/n-cpu.failure
2016-08-01 07:20:14.457 | +functions-common:service_check:1646       failures=/opt/stack/status/stack/n-cpu.failure
2016-08-01 07:20:14.463 | +functions-common:service_check:1648       for service in '$failures'
2016-08-01 07:20:14.472 | ++functions-common:service_check:1649       basename /opt/stack/status/stack/n-cpu.failure
2016-08-01 07:20:14.480 | +functions-common:service_check:1649       service=n-cpu.failure
2016-08-01 07:20:14.487 | +functions-common:service_check:1650       service=n-cpu
2016-08-01 07:20:14.494 | +functions-common:service_check:1651       echo 'Error: Service n-cpu is not running'
2016-08-01 07:20:14.494 | Error: Service n-cpu is not running
2016-08-01 07:20:14.500 | +functions-common:service_check:1654       '[' -n /opt/stack/status/stack/n-cpu.failure ']'
2016-08-01 07:20:14.506 | +functions-common:service_check:1655       die 1655 'More details about the above errors can be found with screen'
2016-08-01 07:20:14.513 | +functions-common:die:186                  local exitcode=0
2016-08-01 07:20:14.519 | [Call Trace]
2016-08-01 07:20:14.519 | ./stack.sh:1346:service_check
2016-08-01 07:20:14.519 | /home/devstackdemo/devstack/functions-common:1655:die
2016-08-01 07:20:14.523 | [ERROR] /home/devstackdemo/devstack/functions-common:1655 More details about the above errors can be found with screen
2016-08-01 07:20:15.526 | Error on exit
```

Comment: attach the error logs!

Comment: Just fixed it. Thanks Hamza !