# Devstack install: n-cpu and q-l3 failure after running ./stack.sh

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, openstack, openstack-nova, devstack

I'm trying to install DevStack Mitaka:

During ./stack.sh execution, n-cpu and q-l3 services fail to start. Error in both screens (n-cpu and q-l3) shows the following:

```
CRITICAL nova [req-..] TypeError: 'Version object does not support
indexing
```

Similar question is marked as solved but there is not answer ([n-cpu failure after running ./stack.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719373/n-cpu-failure-after-running-stack-sh))

Here is the error LOG:

```
+./stack.sh:main:1337                      [[ -x /opt/stack/devstack/local.sh ]]

+./stack.sh:main:1346                      service_check

+functions-common:service_check:1633       local service

+functions-common:service_check:1634       local failures

+functions-common:service_check:1635       SCREEN_NAME=stack

+functions-common:service_check:1636       SERVICE_DIR=/opt/stack
/status

+functions-common:service_check:1639       [[ ! -d /opt/stack/status
/stack ]]

++functions-common:service_check:1646       ls /opt/stack/status/stack
/n-cpu.failure /opt/stack/status/stack/q-l3.failure

+functions-common:service_check:1646       failures='/opt/stack/status/stack/n-cpu.failure

/opt/stack/status/stack/q-l3.failure'

+functions-common:service_check:1648       for service in '$failures'

++functions-common:service_check:1649       basename /opt/stack/status
/stack/n-cpu.failure

+functions-common:service_check:1649       service=n-cpu.failure

+functions-common:service_check:1650       service=n-cpu

+functions-common:service_check:1651       echo 'Error: Service n-cpu 
is not running'

Error: Service n-cpu is not running

+functions-common:service_check:1648       for service in '$failures'

++functions-common:service_check:1649       basename /opt/stack/status
/stack/q-l3.failure

+functions-common:service_check:1649       service=q-l3.failure

+functions-common:service_check:1650       service=q-l3

+functions-common:service_check:1651       echo 'Error: Service q-l3 
is not running'

Error: Service q-l3 is not running

+functions-common:service_check:1654       '[' -n '/opt/stack/status/stack/n-cpu.failure

/opt/stack/status/stack/q-l3.failure' ']'

+functions-common:service_check:1655       die 1655 'More details 
about the above errors can be found with screen'

+functions-common:die:186                  local exitcode=0

[Call Trace]

./stack.sh:1346:service_check

/opt/stack/devstack/functions-common:1655:die

[ERROR] /opt/stack/devstack/functions-common:1655 More details about the above errors can be found with screen

Error on exit
```

Answer (score 1):

sometimes it helps to run clean.sh and run stack.sh again. If you notice same error again, you need to dig into logs and post the error here.

Comment: I've run a complete devstack (Mitaka) install from scratch two times, same results.This seems to be similar to the case reported by @Anurag Anand (see above) . From the logs, there could be an issue with python oslo_util package:  

_[08-30 10:22:49.975 TRACE neutron _[01;35m_[00m  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/versionutils.py", line 49, in is_compatible
_[08-30 10:22:49.975 TRACE neutron _[01;35m_[00m    if same_major and (requested_parts[0] != current_parts[0]):
_[10:22:49.975 TRACE neutron _[01;35m_[00mTypeError: 'Version' object does not support indexing